# How do you resize a cloned jQuery UI element (image)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, clone

I have some particular need to clone an element (image) and be draggable inside a container and still retain its draggable (but not clone) once inside.

I want to make only the cloned elements dragged inside the container to also be  re-sizable, but I cannot get it to work.

I can only get the parent element to resize. Is there any way to only .resize the cloned element?

Somewhat wonky but working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rGUma/4/

Code:

```
<div class="drag"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="drag"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="drag"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="drop-zone"></div>


  <script>
    $(".drop-zone").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
                $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                     containment: '.drop-zone'
                }));
            }
        }
    });
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    //this works but I dont want it on outside elements
     $( '.drag' ).resizable({  
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
    });

     //this doesn't work on cloned images but what I want working       
    $( '.drop-zone img' ).resizable({  
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
    });        

    // '.inside-drop-zone img'  also doesnt work

});​

</script>
```

ps. If someone can explain why it doesn't work it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the clone is never set to be resizable. The `.resizable` is only applied to the elements that exist in the beginning, not to any new elements you create.

I move the resizable call into the cloning portion to apply it to the clone. This also means that the outside boxes are not resizable, per your comments int the source ([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGUma/5/)):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".drop-zone").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
                $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                    containment: '.drop-zone'
                }));

                $clone.resizable({ //this works but I dont want it to on outside elements
                    helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });


    $('.drop-zone img').resizable({ //this doesn't work because its cloned "inside" but its what I want working
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
    });


    // '.inside-drop-zone img'  also doesnt work
    // 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the resizable creation to some kind of event when the clone is born?

```
$('.drop-zone').on('hover', '.drag', function() {
    $(this).resizable({  
       helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
$clone.children().resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});
```

and all images under `class: drop-zone` will be re-sizable.